# Unity c# Cannot return a value from iterators. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Hello i got this error wen i updated unity 
Assets/TCG/Scripts/card.cs(1232,71): error CS1622: Cannot return a value from iterators. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration

I looked at the code a bunch of times played around with it and i cant fix it i looked for a fixes but there non i can understant that good so can someone help me heres the code if you need the hole code tell me i will add it this is the part that the error shows .

```
IEnumerator PayAdditionalCostAndPlay()
{
    if (DiscardCost > 0 && ValidSpell())
    {
        Player.ActionCancelled = false;
        Player.targets.Clear();
        Debug.Log("this card has an additional discard cost");

        for (int i = 0; i < DiscardCost; i++)
        {
            Player.NeedTarget = 21; // a card in hand to discard

            while (Player.NeedTarget > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
            if (Player.ActionCancelled) 
            { 
                Debug.Log("action cancelled"); 
                return false; 
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject target in Player.targets) //discard
        {
            target.GetComponent<card>().Discard();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are simply trying to exit the co-routine when the ActionCancelled is set to true, A slight modification and you end up with this.

You cannot return a value in a co-routine but what you can do is call an external method and BREAK the (stops the forloop in it's tracks)

```
    IEnumerator PayAdditionalCostAndPlay()
    {
        if (DiscardCost > 0 && ValidSpell())
        {
            Player.ActionCancelled = false;
            Player.targets.Clear();
            Debug.Log("this card has an additional discard cost");
            for (int i = 0; i < DiscardCost; i++)
            {
                Player.NeedTarget = 21; // a card in hand to discard

                while (Player.NeedTarget > 0) yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
                if (Player.ActionCancelled)
                {
                    Debug.Log("action cancelled");
                    OnPlayerActionCancelled(); // optional, obviously
                    break; // stop processing the for-loop
                }
            }
            if (!Player.ActionCancelled)
            {
                foreach (GameObject target in Player.targets) //discard
                    target.GetComponent<card>().Discard();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPlayerActionCancelled()
    {
        // Do something when a player action is cancelled
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A single method cannot both `yield return` and `return`. You must choose one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `return` inside co-routine, if you want to stop the co-routine execution use `yield break` instead of `return false` as follows -

```
IEnumerator PayAdditionalCostAndPlay()
{       
    if (DiscardCost > 0 && ValidSpell()) 
    {
        Player.ActionCancelled = false;
        Player.targets.Clear();
        Debug.Log("this card has an additional discard cost");
        for (int i = 0; i < DiscardCost; i++) 
        {
            Player.NeedTarget = 21; // a card in hand to discard

            while (Player.NeedTarget > 0)
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
            if (Player.ActionCancelled) {
                Debug.Log("action cancelled");
                yield break;
            }
        }
        foreach (GameObject target in Player.targets) //discard
            target.GetComponent<card>().Discard();
    }
}
```